# Module Dependency in Prism

Tags: .net, wpf, unity-container, prism

i am trying to code something similar to the project 'Modularity with unity'. i built 2 modules: Module A (loaded via code) and Module D (loaded from directory). both are loaded successfully.

The link which i am taking as reference is https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921068(v=pandp.40).aspx
Source code can be taken from the above link

but when i try to set dependency it's not working. i can't really figure out where the dependency is mentioned in this project. (i set the dependency as attribute in ModuleA class, moduleD is copied after build) this is my implementation:

Bootstrapper.cs

```
protected override IModuleCatalog CreateModuleCatalog()
{
    return new AggregateModuleCatalog();
}

 protected override void ConfigureModuleCatalog()
{
    base.ConfigureModuleCatalog();

    Type moduleAType = typeof(ModuleAModule);
    ModuleCatalog.AddModule(new ModuleInfo()
    {
        ModuleName = ModuleNames.ModuleA,
        ModuleType = moduleAType.AssemblyQualifiedName
    });    

    DirectoryModuleCatalog directoryCatalog = new DirectoryModuleCatalog() { ModulePath = @".\Modules" };
    ((AggregateModuleCatalog)ModuleCatalog).AddCatalog(directoryCatalog);
}

protected override void ConfigureContainer()
{
    base.ConfigureContainer();

    this.RegisterTypeIfMissing(typeof(IModuleTracker), typeof(ModuleTracker), true);
}
```

ModuleA.cs

```
[Module(ModuleName = ModuleNames.ModuleA)]
public class ModuleAModule : IModule
{
    private ILoggerFacade _logger;
    private IModuleTracker _moduleTracker;

    public ModuleAModule(ILoggerFacade logger, IModuleTracker moduleTracker)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _moduleTracker = moduleTracker;

        _moduleTracker.ModuleConstructed("ModuleA");
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        _logger.Log("ModuleA demonstrates logging during Initialize().", Category.Info, Priority.Medium);

        _moduleTracker.ModuleInitialized("ModuleA");
    }
}
```

ModuleD.cs

```
[Module(ModuleName = ModuleNames.ModuleD)]
public class ModuleDModule : IModule
{
    private ILoggerFacade _logger;
    private IModuleTracker _moduleTracker;

    public ModuleDModule(ILoggerFacade logger, IModuleTracker moduleTracker)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _moduleTracker = moduleTracker;

        _moduleTracker.ModuleConstructed("ModuleD");
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        _moduleTracker.ModuleInitialized("ModuleD");
    }
}
```

Comment: **No answer yet, Please help me out on this.**

Answer (score 0):

Add the ModuleDependency attribute in ModuleA.cs

```
[Module(ModuleName = ModuleNames.ModuleA)]    
[ModuleDependency(ModuleNames.ModuleD)]
public class ModuleAModule : IModule
{
    private ILoggerFacade _logger;
    private IModuleTracker _moduleTracker;

    public ModuleAModule(ILoggerFacade logger, IModuleTracker moduleTracker)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _moduleTracker = moduleTracker;

        _moduleTracker.ModuleConstructed("ModuleA");
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        _logger.Log("ModuleA demonstrates logging during Initialize().", Category.Info, Priority.Medium);

        _moduleTracker.ModuleInitialized("ModuleA");
    }
}
```

Comment: Although your answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless 
if that link is moved, changed, merged into another one or the main site 
just disappears... **:-(** Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy 
the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing 
your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! **;-)** You can always 
leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your 
material...